# Activate Function from child class Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I want to trigger a function out of a child class in flutter.
This is the part where the function should be triggered

```
onTap: onItemTap,
```

I tried passing the function on like this:

Parent:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(onItemTap(_selectedIndex))
```

Function in parent:

```
  void _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

Child:

```
  final void Function(int _selectedIndex) onItemTap;
  const BottomBar( this.onItemTap);
```

But I get this error in my Parent:

> ```
> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used
> ```

How do I pass the function on properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_onItemTap` as a tear-off directly, just do:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(_onItemTap)
```

The `BottomBar` expects a `void Function(int _selectedIndex)` which literally means ***A void function that takes one parameter that is an int*** since `_onItemTap` is exactly that, it can be passed directly.

Comment: it works, but why dont I need the parameters? Does flutter know automatically which value to take?

Comment: It is how you pass function as parameter. If you call _onItemTap(someIndex), you are actually calling the function there and passing the result. If you give just the name and signature matches for the function expected, you pass reference to the function.